# MySQL conditional statement

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements

Alright, so I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
            `menu_items`.`name`, 
            ' ($',
            FORMAT(`menu_items`.`price`,2),
            ')'
        ) SEPARATOR '<br>'
    ) as `items`,
    SUM(`menu_items`.`price`) as `additional`,
    `children`.`first_name`,
    `children`.`last_name`,
    `organizations`.`base_price`
FROM 
    `orders`, `order_items`, `menu_items`, `children`, `organizations`
WHERE 
    `order_items`.`menu_item_id` = `menu_items`.`id` AND 
    `order_items`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` AND
    `orders`.`added_by` = {$user_id} AND
    `orders`.`date` > '{$cutoff}' AND
    `children`.`id` = `orders`.`child_id` AND
    `organizations`.`id` = `children`.`organization_id`
GROUP BY 
    `orders`.`id`
```

I know it's a monstrosity and that some people will die before not using explicit joins. Ignoring that, however, what I wish to do is to only use the `CONCAT` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` if the `menu_items.price` is greater than 0, otherwise only return `menu_items.name`. I have had, however, no success trying to throw an `IF` in there. I've read the manual but all the ways that I've tried aren't working and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something on the whole conditional statements thing.

Comment: oooh, the string formatting inside SQL makes me angry! Especially the <br>, no danger of MVC here! :) With that off my chest, you could always wrap the CONCATed string with a REPLACE(X, '<br> ($0.00)', '') if you can't figure anything else out.

Comment: Hahaha. Well sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do. And that does the trick. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using something like this?

```
CASE WHEN 'menu_items'.'price' = 0 THEN 'menu.items'.'name' ELSE CONCAT (etc) END
```

Replacing the `CONCAT` statement of course.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (but I didn't test it, sorry):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
    `menu_items`.`name`, 
    IF(`menu_items`.`price` > 0,                          -- <condition>
      CONCAT(' ($', FORMAT(`menu_items`.`price`,2), ')'), -- <true-expr>
      ''                                                  -- <false-expr>
    )
  )
  SEPARATOR '<br>'
) as `items`,
```

The `IF()` function is really simple:

```
IF( <condition>, <true-expr>, <false-expr> )
```

The function has three arguments:  the first is `<condition>`.  If the condition evaluates to true, the function returns the result of `<true-expr>`.  Else the function returns the result of `<false-expr>`.

Things get harder to get right when you use really long, multi-line expressions that contain parentheses and commas and so on.  You just have to do it carefully.  I suggest starting with more simple expressions and then build up.